# How does Golang's LDAP client library work with certificates?

Tags: go, ldap, google-workspace

I'm trying to connect to [G Suite's LDAPS server](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9089736?hl=en) with [Golang's LDAP library](http://github.com/go-ldap/ldap).

However, in the [example](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/ldap.v3?tab=doc#example-package-UserAuthentication), I don't really understand two things.

1. It seems like it connects via non-encrypted LDAP first? Then it upgrades? Is that true, if so, can't I just start out by connecting encrypted?
2. Google supplies a .cer & .key file to connect to their ldap server. I don't see where it use these files. I do see in their docs that a lot of LDAP clients require the files to be combined into a .p12. Is that necessary for Go?

If the person that answers this could supply an example, that would really help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`StartTLS`, as you've noted, allows one to upgrade a connection to use a `TLS` later on in the connections lifecycle.

If you want to connect via `TLS` immediately, then use the well known `ldaps` port `636` (instead of `389`) - and use DialTLS:

```
// l, err := ldap.Dial("tcp", "ldap.example.com:389"))

var tlsConf *tls.Config

ldaps, err := ldap.DialTLS("tcp", "gsuite.google.com:636", tlsConf)
```

You may also use `DialURL` which infers TLS or non-TLS by the schema e.g.

```
conn, err := ldap.DialURL("ldap://ldap.example.com") // non-TLS on default port 389
conn, err := ldap.DialURL("ldaps://ldap.example.com") // TLS on default port 636
conn, err := ldap.DialURL("ldaps://myserver.com:1234") // TLS on custom port 1234

// Note: there is no way to add a custom tls.Config with this method
```

---

So if using, `DialTLS`: since you are using a Google service, it's trust cert should already be in your keychain, so a simple `tls.Config` should suffice:

```
tlsConf = &tls.Config{ServerName:"gsuite.google.com"} // <- ensure this matches the hostname provided by the server
```

If you want to get things up an running for testing:

```
// DONT EVER USE THIS IN PRODUCTION...
tlsConf = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true} // DO NOT USE EVER
```

---

To add a client cert for client-side authentication:

```
// Load cer & key files into a pair of []byte 
cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(cer, key)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
tlsCong := &tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what would tlsConfig look like with .cer and .key certificate files?

Comment: Updated answer with client-cert auth info.

Comment: Thanks! I should be able to test later and accept the answer.